# JavaScript: this-keyword access problem in arrow functions

Tags: javascript, this

```
const user = {
    name: "Praveen",
    videos: ["html", "css", "js"],
    
    greet() {
        console.log(`welcome ${this.name}`);
        const getVideos = () => {
            console.log(`You have ${this.videos.length} videos`);
        };
        getVideos();
      },
    };
user.greet();
```

I am able to access the value of the `videos.length` in the above code (I have used arrow function), but I am not able to access the value of the `videos.length` in the below code:

```
const user = {
    name: "Praveen",
    videos: ["html", "css", "js"],
    
    greet() {
        console.log(`welcome ${this.name}`);
        const getVideos = function () {
          console.log(`You have ${this.videos.length} videos`);
        };
        getVideos();
      },
    };
user.greet();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function defined with keyword `function` will has its own `this`, while arrow function doesn't ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#this_and_Arrow_Functions))

So in your case, when you use arrow function in example 1, the `this` will refer to `user`, while in example 2, `this` will refer to `getVideos`

To resolve this, you could store `this` of the `user` into a new variable

```js
const user = {
  name: "Praveen",
  videos: ["html", "css", "js"],

  greet() {
    console.log(`welcome ${this.name}`)
    const self = this // notice me
    const getVideos = function () {
      console.log(`You have ${self.videos.length} videos`)
    }
    getVideos()
  },
}
user.greet()
```

Or use `call` and then apply the `this` reference of `user` to `getVideos`

```js
const user = {
  name: "Praveen",
  videos: ["html", "css", "js"],

  greet() {
    console.log(`welcome ${this.name}`)
    const getVideos = function () {
      console.log(`You have ${this.videos.length} videos`)
    }
    getVideos.call(this) // notice me
  },
}
user.greet()
```

Answer (score 1):

`getVideos()` is called with no context, therefore `this` refers to the window object.

The preferred way to get around this is using an arrow function, as seen in your first example.

A pre-arrow function way was to do something like this:

```
const user = {
  name: "Praveen",
  videos: ["html", "css", "js"],

  greet() {
    console.log(`welcome ${this.name}`);
    const that = this;  // <---- that now refers to this context
    const getVideos = function () {
      console.log(`You have ${that.videos.length} videos`);   // <--- use that instead of this
    };
    getVideos();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you should use arrow functions.
here is the HTML code with JavaScript will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
       const user = {
      name: "Praveen",
      videos: ["html", "css", "js"],
    
      greet() {
        console.log(`welcome ${this.name}`);
        const getVideos = () => {
          console.log(`You have ${this.videos.length} videos`);
        };
        getVideos();
      },
    };
    user.greet();
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```